# Why ColorStateList doesn't work with GradientDrawable?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, statelistdrawable, gradientdrawable

I'm trying to set *TestView* background with **GradientDrawable** that is set for different states.
When using methods: **setStroke** and **setColor** (that gets **ColorStateList**) for a **GradientDrawable** it seems that the **ColorStateList** is being ignored.
For the following code:

```
  int frameColor = Color.parseColor("#000000");
    GradientDrawable charFrameDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
    ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(new int[][]{{android.R.attr.state_activated}}, new int[]{frameColor});
    charFrameDrawable.setStroke(1, colorStateList);
    charFrameDrawable.setColor(colorStateList);
     textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setBackground(charFrameDrawable);

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    int[] arr =textView.getBackground().getState();
    for (int i =0; i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        Log.e("12345",String.valueOf(arr[i]));

    }
```

I'm getting the following output:

2020-07-01 03:21:45.776 29138-29138/com.example.testcheckbox E/12345: 16842910
2020-07-01 03:21:45.776 29138-29138/com.example.testcheckbox E/12345: 16843597

As you can see i'm getting two id's although there is only one state, and the first id belong to *state_enabled* const (which isn't part of the state i set).
Can someone help me with the issue?
Thanks